# Composer updates hangs while composer install is working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, vagrant, homestead

I am running my laravel projects on homestead (vagrant with VirtualBox)
Previously it was all well but suddenly the `composer update` command started to hangs. If I tried to install any packages too it hangs but the `composer install` is running correctly. I read a couple of solutions and tried to do that. I increase my **Virtual box memory to 4GB** and tried some commands like

```
composer cache-clear
```

But the result is still the same.
But I try to run `composer update` using XAMPP from the same PC outside the vagrant It works correctly

**NOTE:** `composer update` hangs on every project on the homestead (Not on a specific project)

My `composer.json`

```
    {
    "name": "xxx",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "E-commerce app",
    "keywords": [
        "xxx",
        "books"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "4.7.*",
        "arcanedev/no-captcha": "^5.0",
        "brackets/admin-listing": "^2.0",
        "brackets/admin-ui": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "hieu-le/active": "^3.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.0",
        "laravel/telescope": "^2.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelista/comments": "^3.1",
        "plank/laravel-mediable": "^2.9",
        "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^3.7",
        "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "laravel/dusk": "^5.0",
        "laravel/homestead": "^8.2",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files" : [
            "tests/utilities/functions.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `composer.json`?

Comment: Please check I have added

Comment: does your vagrant box use a swap partition? 4gb might sound like enough but it might not be. A swap partition might help take some of the load off.

Comment: I dont know how to do that ??

Comment: Try [this solution for increasing swap memory](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors) and make sure you [allow the install process to take up enough memory](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors)